# How to hide player from android notification panel during video cutscene in webgl build on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, unity-webgl

I have video cutscene in my unity web game. Videoplayer component playing from source url, mp4 video file, which located in StreamingAssets folder. Everythings works well, but i need to hide player from android notification panel during cutscene. How can i do that?

I tried to separate video and audio, set DecompressOnLoad on audio clip. It works, but sometimes gets desynchronization between them.
Maybe there is another way?